# Is it possible to detect if a matplotlib artist is a mappable suitable for use with colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Some matplotlib functions (e.g., `contourf` and `imshow`) return artist objects that can be used to produce colorbars when passed as the `mappable` argument to [colorbars](http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html). Other objects (e.g., `plot`) return artists that are not mappable.

Is it is possible to detect if an artist is such a suitable object? I'd like to write an API that uses arbitrary `pyplot` functions, and lets me add a colorbar after the fact based on the last function that returned a `mappable`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hack I used in the past:

```
hasattr(cs, 'autoscale_None')
```

Not sure if this holds for all Artists though.  It is usually OK telling lines and points apart from colorbar-material mappables (countour(f), pcolor, scatter, etc).

Comment: The reason for doing this is in the Colorbar class at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/colorbar.py#L880